# Python: Float or Double

Tags: python, types, floating-point, double

I need to pack numbers in Python using the `struct` module. I want to check if a number is `float` or `double`, when I pack it. How can I do that? Is there any built-in functions, or I need to write one? Or I need to write a class for simple `Float`s instead of using python's `float`s(which are actually `Double`s)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python does not have C-style `float`, it only has a C-style `double`, which is called `float`.

You must decide yourself whether you need the extra precision of a `double` when you design your structures. Or, rather, you must decide whether gaining a bit of space efficiency is worth the loss of precision.